# Prevent consecutive api navigation calls in visualforce pages - Release update

Tags: visualforce, release-update

I have an issue related to the release update. Here's the link for the release update [article](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=release-notes.rn_vf_navigation_calls.htm&type=5&release=232).

According to this release update, it will prevent the unwanted behaviour of multiple API navigation calls that fires consecutively in vf pages. With this release update only the first navigation call will fire.

I have tried to replicate the impact of this release update so I have created a visualforce page that has two api navigation calls. When I tested it on Desktop and mobile without enabling the release update, every time the first navigation call fires. It's showing the same behaviour that is mentioned in the release update without enabling it.

Any help would be appreciated.